# High voltage power supply and shunt regulator design

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, high-voltage, shunt

I'm building a high voltage power supply for a tube amplifier preamp and I need some advice.

I need a power supply with a shunt regulator that is rock solid stable and dead quiet and outputs 600v with a maximum of 100ma current draw that will be adjustable down to 2ma.
The next stage of the design requires a stable voltage and the stage will amplify any noise so I need a good design.

This is what I have right now
[image]

I don't trust the stability or noise of that series regulator design. After building it in real life it seems to droop a few volts and I'm not sure what to think about the noise.

The resistor in the RC filter is underlined with question marks because I don't know the shunt design or overhead voltage that I will need for it.

Does anyone have any advice on a quality shunt regulator with as low noise as possible?

Comment: What parts did you use for Q1, Q4 and D6? What measurements have you made?

Comment: IRF840 for Q1 and Q4. D6 was http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Semiconductors/BZX85B100-TAP/?qs=WLTup5mM6hhYlWQnzZDHKw%3D%3D 1.3w 100v zener in series with a 56v equivalent for a 200v output power supply. It dropped several volts under load. I need a shunt regulator that won't drop anything.

Comment: That's not a shunt regulator at all- it's a ~475V series regulator (with missing gate protection and dubious stability). What do you actually need?

Comment: Yeah sorry, not sure why I said shunt regulator for the above circuit. Now that you mention it, I'm not sure what it is that I need. Shunt regulators draw maximum current from the power supply at all times right? I've heard shunt has better peformance but then again, maximum current across the RC filter would require a whopping power rating on the resistor.

Comment: Is this preamp for an antenna (if so, what band), or for a microphone? My 'gut' response would be to build/get a PWM SMPS to boost up to ~610V; make sure it operates several octaves outside your frequency band of interest; then add low/high-pass filters to block SMPS noise on Vout & short the noise to GND (i.e. at least 2nd order).

Comment: It's for a tube amplifier.

Comment: I just want to point out that most tube amplifiers do not use high-quality power supplies. The typical approach is just rectified a.c. with a bit of smoothing; normally no regulation is used. "Tube sound" comes in part from an unregulated and relatively high-impedance power supply that sags under load. So it may not be beneficial for your application to pay too much attention to this part of the design, if that application is audio.

Comment: That's true if you want that old-school tube sound. High quality regulated supplies are expensive to add onto a typical produce though. I find the sound is much more refined with a regulated supply. Besides, this is a piece to a bigger puzzle and I need an adjustable CVS on the load which requires a regulated supply.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I just realized a shunt regulator would require far too much constant power draw through the power supply resistors at these voltages. I think I need to go with a series regulator. One that happens to be extremely quite and stable. I would prefer a shunt but I don't think it's an option here.

Comment: Valve stuff generally draws a more constant current than solid state equipment .This looks like high end audio so it will off course be class A so the average current is constant .This means that load regulation in not  important .Your proposed regulator is only for line regulation .You may not need it and its noise .Maybe you could spend the money on more power supply filter caps

Comment: The maximum current draw will be 100ma, far below the maximum draw of the power supply. The anti-triode CVS gyrator load of the input tubes requires dead stable input voltage. This isn't for an output stage it's for the preamp/amplification stage. As far as I know a shunt regulator requires full current draw across its resistor which would require a over 100w of power dissipation. A series regulator only draws what the load draws right?

Comment: OK you can keep your reg and you can post filter if there are still noise concerns .Now be careful about your Powermosfet in linear mode ,it is not as robust as you think.

Comment: Well I don't intend to be using that regulator, it's not stable. Which is why I made the thread :P I need advice on design.

Comment: Try to use just one fet and a stable zener that is about 3V more than you need .You may need to make the stable zener out  of lots of parts .If you do this you wont have any feedback loop stability problems.

Comment: You mean like this? http://img.bhs4.com/14/5/145dd317c026b8df67d4cbc715eacff11b10ded3_large.jpg

Comment: That is a VBe amplifier which will multiply a neg tempco .Why not multiply a hopefully neutral temp co .

Comment: Can you explain that a little further? How does tempco fit into this?

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would make this regulator?